# Is $|K/\tau|\leq 1$?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\alpha:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a regular curve such that $\alpha'$ and $\alpha''$ are linearly independent over $[a,b]$.

Let $K$ and $\tau$ be the curvature and torsion of $\alpha$ respectively and assume $K\neq 0$.

If $\tau=cK$ for some constant $c\in\mathbb{R}$, then is $|c|\leq 1$?

How do I prove that?

Comment: In fact, the torsion and the curvature can be arbitrary functions, more or less! If you pick a $K$ and a $\tau$ defined on $[a,b]$ (and under minimal conditions) there is a curve with that curvature and torsion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\alpha(t)=(a\cos t,a\sin t,bt)$ be a [*Helix curve*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helix). Now $|\tau|=\frac{|b|}{a^2+b^2}=\frac{|b|}{|a|}\frac{|a|}{a^2+b^2}=\frac{|b|}{|a|}|\kappa|=|c|\kappa$.

Here you can choose $|a|<|b|$, to make $|c|>1$.